# How to send authorization token with nodejs using request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am trying to send authorization token to get data from external api but i dont see data in response , what is correct approach to get data using `request` module ?

app.js

```
var request = require('request');

router.get('/stream', (req, res) => {
  // Get posts from the mock api
  var data;
  var headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
      'Authorization': 'Basic bTA5NDg1QGNvbGYXR0LmNvbTpjYnVzTVNAMjAxNw=='
  }
  var options = {
    url: 'http://la/service/getHistoricEvents',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
    data: {'agentId': 'ssjy9u'}
  }

  request(options, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
      console.dir(err)
      return
    }
    data = body;
  })
    res.status(200).json(data);
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass data to Get request?

Comment: Also put res.status(200).json(data) inside the callback function in request.

Comment: i have to send id and authorization in header to get the data

Comment: i tried to put res inside callback it throws error res is not a function

Comment: That's because you have same variable 'res' at 2 places. One in request callback and on in router. Get callback. Rename one of them and try

Comment: thats ok first thing is to get data from api and that coming from api response, once i have response i can make variable changes you suggested

Comment: should not you use `qs:{'agentId': 'ssjy9u'}` rather than `data:{'agentId': 'ssjy9u'}` ?